# How to set limit for snapshotChanges lisitner

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using angular ngx admin and I need to read only  ones or 2, How to do that?

```
this.firestore
  .collection(tablePages, (ref) =>
    ref
      .where("page.title", "==", pageName)
      .where("projectId", "==", localStorage.getItem("projectId"))
  )
  .snapshotChanges()
  .forEach((value) => {
    value.forEach((val) => {
      let p: MillaPage = val.payload.doc.data()["page"] as MillaPage;
      if (p != null) {
        p.id = val.payload.doc.id;

        this.mApp.pages.push(p);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of documents that are read from Firestore, you can [place a limit on the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

```
ref.where('page.title', '==', pageName)
   .where('projectId', '==', localStorage.getItem('projectId')
   .limit(2)
```

Comment: This will limit the document count, but I what I need is if I set the limit and if I make an update in that doc it is calling again. How to stop that? I don't want to limit the doc count i need to unsubscribe the snapshotChanges

Comment: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction<unknown>[]>'.
    
    142                 .snapshotChanges().take(1).forEach((value) => {

Comment: I believe that the snapshot is needed for when you update/delete your document, there is an explanation of this at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608769/what-is-snapshotchanges-in-firestore) at the 3th answer.